# Content Hub Javascript SDK is throwing Error: Cannot find module 'form-data'

Tags: content-hub

I am trying to authenticate and create a Content Hub client using CH Javascript SDK based on [this document](https://docs.stylelabs.com/content/4.1.x/integrations/javascript-sdk/authentication.html)

I have installed the npm package as described in [this document](https://docs.stylelabs.com/content/4.1.x/integrations/javascript-sdk/getting-started.html?tabs=tabid-2)

I am getting the below error on compilation.

```
error - ./node_modules/@sitecore/sc-contenthub-webclient-sdk/dist/clients/upload-client.js:17:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'form-data'
null
Error: Cannot find module 'form-data'
Require stack:
- D:\Work\Blog Materials\JAMStack\Nextjs\my-photo-blog\node_modules\@sitecore\sc-contenthub-webclient-sdk\dist\clients\upload-client.js       
- D:\Work\Blog Materials\JAMStack\Nextjs\my-photo-blog\node_modules\@sitecore\sc-contenthub-webclient-sdk\dist\clients\content-hub-client.js  
- D:\Work\Blog Materials\JAMStack\Nextjs\my-photo-blog\.next\server\pages\about.js
- D:\Work\Blog Materials\JAMStack\Nextjs\my-photo-blog\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\require.js
- D:\Work\Blog Materials\JAMStack\Nextjs\my-photo-blog\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\load-components.js
- D:\Work\Blog Materials\JAMStack\Nextjs\my-photo-blog\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\api-utils.js
- D:\Work\Blog Materials\JAMStack\Nextjs\my-photo-blog\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-server.js
- D:\Work\Blog Materials\JAMStack\Nextjs\my-photo-blog\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.js
- D:\Work\Blog Materials\JAMStack\Nextjs\my-photo-blog\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js
- D:\Work\Blog Materials\JAMStack\Nextjs\my-photo-blog\node_modules\next\dist\cli\next-dev.js
- D:\Work\Blog Materials\JAMStack\Nextjs\my-photo-blog\node_modules\next\dist\bin\next
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.mod._resolveFilename (D:\Work\Blog Materials\JAMStack\Nextjs\my-photo-blog\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\require-hook.js:4:1855)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Work\Blog Materials\JAMStack\Nextjs\my-photo-blog\node_modules\@sitecore\sc-contenthub-webclient-sdk\dist\clients\upload-client.js:17:37)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'D:\\Work\\Blog Materials\\JAMStack\\Nextjs\\my-photo-blog\\node_modules\\@sitecore\\sc-contenthub-webclient-sdk\\dist\\clients\\upload-client.js',
    'D:\\Work\\Blog Materials\\JAMStack\\Nextjs\\my-photo-blog\\node_modules\\@sitecore\\sc-contenthub-webclient-sdk\\dist\\clients\\content-hub-client.js',
    'D:\\Work\\Blog Materials\\JAMStack\\Nextjs\\my-photo-blog\\.next\\server\\pages\\about.js',
    'D:\\Work\\Blog Materials\\JAMStack\\Nextjs\\my-photo-blog\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\next-server\\server\\require.js',
    'D:\\Work\\Blog Materials\\JAMStack\\Nextjs\\my-photo-blog\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\next-server\\server\\load-components.js',
    'D:\\Work\\Blog Materials\\JAMStack\\Nextjs\\my-photo-blog\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\next-server\\server\\api-utils.js',
    'D:\\Work\\Blog Materials\\JAMStack\\Nextjs\\my-photo-blog\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\next-server\\server\\next-server.js',
    'D:\\Work\\Blog Materials\\JAMStack\\Nextjs\\my-photo-blog\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\server\\next.js',
    'D:\\Work\\Blog Materials\\JAMStack\\Nextjs\\my-photo-blog\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\server\\lib\\start-server.js',
    'D:\\Work\\Blog Materials\\JAMStack\\Nextjs\\my-photo-blog\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\cli\\next-dev.js',
    'D:\\Work\\Blog Materials\\JAMStack\\Nextjs\\my-photo-blog\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\bin\\next'
  ]
}
```

Have you seen this error? How can I resolve this?

Comment: I should clarify that I am trying to use CH Javascript SDK from nextjs application.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by running the below npm command

npm install --save form-data

It seems CH Javascript SDK installation had not included this  this dependency. When I installed SDK there was no indication that form-data module is missing.